# get instance variable name from itself in ruby

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have an instance variable `@foo` and I want to write some code so that I get string `'foo'`

any hint?

Comment: code smell... what's the use case?

Comment: meta programming is not to smell, but to be addicted to. Am defiantly doing it wrong, but still being curious

Answer (score 7):

If all you have is a reference to the object, you can't really do it cleanly.

```
def foo
  bar @something
end

def bar(value)
  value # no clean way to know this is @something
end
```

---

The only hack I can think of is to loop through ALL instance variables on `self`, looking for matches.  But its a very messy approach that's likely to be slow.

```
def bar(value)
  instance_variables.each do |ivar_name|
    if instance_variable_get(ivar_name) == value
      return ivar_name.to_s.sub(/^@/, '') # change '@something' to 'something'
    end
  end

  # return nil if no match was found
  nil 
end

@something = 'abc123'
bar @something # returns 'something'

# But passing the same value, will return a value it's equal to as well
bar 'abc123' # returns 'something'
```

This works because `instance_variables` returns an array of symbols that are the names of instance variables.

```
instance_variables
#=> [:@something, :@whatever]
```

And `instance_variable_get` allows you to fetch the value by it's name.

```
instance_variable_get :@something # note the @
#=> 'abc123'
```

Combine the two methods and you can get close to what you want.

---

Just use it wisely. Before using a solution based on this, see if you can refactor things a way so that it's not necessary. Meta-programming is like a martial art. You should know how it works, but have the discipline to avoid using it whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby, you can only manipulate objects. Variables (including instance variables) aren't objects.

Besides, what do you want your magic method to return in this case:

```
foo = Object.new
bar = foo
@baz = bar
@qux = bar

magic_method(foo) # what should the return value be and how would it know?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call the method `instance_variables` to get the name of all instance variables of an object. Caution though that instance variables are only included in that list *after* they have been initialized.

```
>> class A; attr_accessor :foo; end
=> nil
>> a = A.new
=> #<A:0x103b310b0>
>> a.instance_variables
=> []
>> a.foo = 42
=> 42
>> a.instance_variables
=> ["@foo"]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
class Object
    def get_name
      line_number = caller[0].split(':')[1].to_i
      line_exectued = File.readlines( __FILE__)[line_number-1]
      line_exectued.match(/(\S+).get_name/)[1]
    end
end

inconceivable = true

p inconceivable.get_name
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally frowned upon on this site. Could you please edit your answer to include some comments or explanation of your code? Explanations should answer questions like: What does it do? How does it do it? Where does it go? How does it solve OP's problem? See: [How to anwser](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks!