# any way capture the name of a constant on declaration?

Tags: ruby

I have a class. Let's call it SomeClass:

```
class SomeClass
end
```

Instead of defining instances of this class the normal way, I would like to define them all using a constant:

```
MyConstant = SomeClass.new
```

I want to be able to capture the name of the constant that some class was set too, in much the same way that standard ruby classes do with the .class method.

```
MyConstant.name #-> "MyConstant"
```

I want to be able to do this to render better error messages from all instances of some class, like so:

```
class SomeClass 
  def display_error_message 
    "Error, some class #{self.name} has a problem"
  end
end

MyConstant.display_error_message
#-> "Error, some class MyConstant has a problem"
```

Any way to accomplish this?

EDIT

---

Here's an example to clarify what I'm shooting for.

(Enum is the name of the class I'm creating, which is meant to act similar to Swifts 'Enum' type. Basically it sets a predefined list of options (:pepperoni, :sausage, :mushroom) with a raw_value ("Pepperoni", "Sausage", "Mushroom".) Obviously in this example a hash or a simple algorithm for converting a symbol to an UpperCamel case string could work, but in reality the enum class will do a lot more, but this example shows the gist of it.

```
class Pizza 
  attr_reader :topping

  Toppings = Enum.new do 
    option(:pepperoni).set("Pepperoni")
    option(:sausage).set("Sausage")
    option(:mushrooms).set("Mushrooms")
  end

  def set_topping(symbol)
    @topping = Toppings[symbol]
  end
end

pizza = Pizza.new

### Happy Case
pizza.set_topping(:pepperoni)

### Sad Case (Error message shown below is what I'm trying to figure out)
pizza.set_topping(:spinach)
#-> Error. enum Toppings has no option spinach
```

Comment: Not a ruby developer, but it any other language I would consider this a hack, and would suggest you might use a subclass instead.

Comment: I'm not suggesting that what you want to do is impossible or that it will result in the apocalypse, but you almost certainly don't want to do what you are asking to do.

Comment: @Evert yes it most definitely is a hack, I just can't seem to find a pattern I like better yet.

Comment: @MarcTalbot Honestly laughed reading that. Yeah it's a little crazy. I'm gonna update the question with an example of what specifically I'm trying to accomplish and maybe one of you guys will be able to see a better way.

Comment: `MyConstant = SomeClass.new` is a little misleading as `MyConstant` is an instance of `SomeClass` not a class, you'd normally say `MY_CONSTANT = SomeClass.new` to avoid confusion. The object referenced by `MY_CONSTANT` doesn't really have a name unless you add a name by hand (i.e. `def name` or equivalent in `SomeClass`) in the same way that `6` in `six = 6` doesn't have a name.

Comment: You might want to have a look at how certain gems resolve your issue. https://rubygems.org/gems/ruby-enum

Comment: You could also let your `Enum` class extend from the `Class` class, add some of your generic enum logic and go from there.

Comment: @JohanWentholt How do you extend from the class Class? I just tried subclassing it the standard way and it gave the error 'can't make subclass of Class.'

Comment: @JoshHadik I never tried it myself, I assumed it would work. I'll post a solution for you below.

Answer (score 4):

A variable is just a way of referring to an object, and the variable's name is irrelevant. If you say `X = Y` and `Y` happens to be a class, then the `Y` class already has the name `"Y"`, so you can't change that.

As far as Ruby is concerned `X` and `Y` are indistinguishable.

If you want to alter the name you can make a subclass even if that subclass doesn't do anything different:

```
X = Class.new(Y)
X.name
# => "X"
Z = X
Z.name
# => "X"
```

That way preserves the name properly but only in the context of the initialization. I think Ruby does something sneaky and if a new class is being assigned to a constant it assigns a name, but for ordinary variables it does not:

```
x = Class.new(Y)
x.name
# => nil
```

So this is a special case.

The key here is that there's a huge difference between a subclass, which does impact the name, and a variable reference, which doesn't.

There's some other strange stuff going on here as it seems like the class somehow "knows" when it's being assigned to something and if that something is a constant it steals the constant's name for itself:

```
z = Class.new
z.name
# => nil
Z = z
z.name
# => "Z"
```

As they say in programming: "Wat?"

Comment: Thanks for the response! Yeah I guess what I'm trying to figure out is what that sneaky thing that Ruby does is. But I'm getting the feeling that's not gonna be possible. At least not in any sane way.

Comment: It never occurred to me to test that behaviour until you asked your question, and the result surprised me. I thought there'd be no difference between `x = Class.new` and `X = Class.new` but there's actually a huge difference. This is even the case with deferred initialization as I show in an edit here. Is there some kind of ill-documented "I've been assigned to a constant" method called on objects?

Comment: @tadman: No. The language spec says that modules "magically" get a name when they are first assigned to a constant, but the language spec does not specify that it has to happen via a hook method, in fact, it doesn't specify any specific mechanism *at all*.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Enum` class could look something like this:

```
class Enum

  def initialize(name, &blk)
    @defined_options = {}
    @name = name.freeze
    instance_eval(&blk)
    @defined_options.freeze
  end

  def [](key)
    if @defined_options.key? key
      @defined_options[key].value
    else
      unfound_option = Option.new(@name, key)
      raise "Option #{unfound_option} not found."
    end
  end

  def to_s
    "#{@name}"
  end

  def inspect
    keys = @defined_options.keys.join(',')
    "#<#{self}::{#{keys}}>"
  end

  class Option
    attr_reader :value

    def initialize(enum_name, key)
      @value_initialized = false
      @enum_name = enum_name
      @key = key
    end

    def set(value)
      if @value_initialized
        raise "Value for #{self} can't be set to #{value} " +
              "because it is already initialized to #{@value}"
      else
        @value_initialized = true
        @value = value.freeze
      end
    end

    def to_s
      "#{@enum_name}::#{@key}"
    end

    def inspect
      "#<#{self}>"
    end

  end

private

  def option(sym)
    unless @defined_options.key? sym
      option = Option.new(@name, sym)
      @defined_options[sym] = option
    end

    @defined_options[sym]
  end

end
```

Now you can almost keep the syntax you have in your question, and do the following:

```
class Pizza 
  attr_reader :topping

  # I had to add the name in the initializer for better error reporting.
  Toppings = Enum.new('Toppings') do
    option(:pepperoni).set("Pepperoni")
    option(:sausage).set("Sausage")
    option(:mushrooms).set("Mushrooms")
  end

  def set_topping(symbol)
    @topping = Toppings[symbol]
  end
end

pizza = Pizza.new

### Happy Case
pizza.set_topping(:pepperoni)
#=> "Pepperoni"

### Sad Case (Error message shown below is what I'm trying to figure out)
pizza.set_topping(:spinach)
#=> RuntimeError: Option Toppings::spinach not found.
```

This might give you an idea how to solve this issue. This is just a rough sketch of the class and could probably be tweaked to your needs.

Comment: Hey man, sorry for the delayed response, just got a chance to look at this. Thanks so much for the response, saved me a lot of time!