# In Rails, what is the cleanest method of getting a variable name preferably in symbol form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, reflection

Suppose you have

```
[started, stopped].each do |action|
   # puts "#{action} is :started" # or
   # puts "#{action} is :stopped"
end
```

Getting the original variable name of the current item (action)
I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074652/3577482, but it requires additional helper methods

Answer (score 1):

Easy solution, put them into a Hash and iterate over that:

```
{
  started: started,
  stopped: stopped
}.each do |name, value|
  puts "name is {name}, value is #{value}"
end
```

Organizing data into *structures* is always a good idea, but it's especially important in Ruby since a lot of Ruby's strength comes from being able to manipulate and transform structures into other structures.

Answer (score 0):

```
[:started, :stopped].each do |key|
  action = self.send(key)
  puts "name is #{key}, value is #{action}"
  ...
end
```

EDIT: 
Was looking for this example which returns the variable meta

Comment: This works *if* `started` and `stopped` are *methods* and not variables. If they're variables you need to do some really dirty things to get them, it's not advised.